# Deciding which template specialization structure to use each time

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have the following declarations in `C++`:

```
template<class T1, class T2> struct canAssign {
    enum { result = false };
};
template<class T1> struct canAssign<T1,T1> {
    enum { result = true };
};
```

And I have the following calls (`A` extends `B`):

```
canAssign<A,A>::result;
canAssign<B,A>::result;
canAssign<B*,A*>::result;
```

I know it uses the `template specialization` feature but I can't seem to understand how it decides which one to choose each time?

**EDIT**: I know what the output should be:

```
true
false
false
```

My question is how the compiler choose the right one? what algorithm/method/approach I need to think in my head in order understand which one will be called

Comment: `canAssign` can be rename `is_same`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I know what should be the output. I don't understand why though (how the compiler chooses the right one)

Comment: is your issue is with inheritance? "more specialized" concept?

Answer (score 0):

Possible inheritance doesn't count here.

So you have:

```
canAssign<A, A>::result;   // true  T1=A, T2=A as T1=T2, use specialization
canAssign<B, A>::result;   // false T1=B, T2=A
canAssign<B*, A*>::result; // false T1=B*, T2=A*
```

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how the compiler choose the right one? what algorithm/method/approach I need to think in my head in order understand which one will be called

The algorithm is described in the [[temp.class.spec.match]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class.spec.match) section (and related ones) of the particular standard you are targeting.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how the compiler choose the right one? what algorithm/method/approach I need to think in my head in order understand which one will be called

The compiler choose the most specialized version available (and gives an error if there is ambiguity selecting the most specialization available).

A version is more specialized than another when

1) all matches, of template parameters, for the more specialized are also matches for the less specialized

2) and there are matches for the less specialized that aren't matches for the more specialized

In your case, you have two version of `canAssign`: the main one and the specialization.

The specialization is, obviously, more specialized than the main version so, in case of

```
canAssign<A,A>::result;
```

bot versions match so the compiler choose the specialization.

In the other cases

```
canAssign<B,A>::result;
canAssign<B*,A*>::result;
```

only the main version matches so the compiler choose the main version.

Another example to better explain the point: suppose you have a template `foo` with two specializations

```
template <typename, typename, typename>
struct foo 
 { };

template <typename A, typename B>
struct foo<A, A, B>
 { };

template <typename A>
struct foo<A, A, A>
 { };
```

The second specialization is more specialized than the fists one.

In fact

1) all sets of template parameter (necessarily all equals) matching the second one necessarily match also the first one (the first and the second are equal)

2) exist at least a set of template parameters (`int`, `int`, `long`, by example) that matches the first one but not the second one.

So:

1) the second specialization is more specialized than the first one

2) the first specialization is more specialized than the main version

So

- `foo<int, int, int>` matches all versions, so the compiler choose the second specialization
- `foo<int, int, long>` matches main version and first specialization, so the compiler choose the first specialization
- `foo<int, long, int>` matches only the main version, so the compiler choose the main version.

Comment: There is only one specialization in play here, so these rules don't apply.

Comment: @Acorn - yes, in the standard the rule is written applying the primary template only when no specialization matches; on the other hand, you can't write a specialization that doesn't specialize (if you try, compiling `template <typename, typename>
struct foo
 { };

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct foo<T1, T2>
 { };` you get an error because the specialization is specialized exactly as the primary template) so I don't see practical differences.

Comment: OP is asking how the compiler decides whether the specialization or the primary template is to be used. The first step is deciding which specializations match (or not). What you described is the ordering between specializations, which happens after matching has happened if there is more than one. In OP's example, there is only one, so what you describe here does not influence the compiler decision.

Answer (score 0):

It is a kind of pattern matching.

This will be a just-so story.  It does not exactly match the standard, but I find it generates good intiution.

```
template<class T1, class T2> struct canAssign {
  enum { result = false };
};
```

this is the primary specilization.  It defines the template signature -- two classes, as defined by `<class T1, class T2>`.  It is also the one that is instantiated if nothing else matches.

```
template<class T1> struct canAssign<T1,T1> {
  enum { result = true };
};
```

this is a secondary specialization.  Here the `<class T1>` serves a different purpose; it introduces variables to pattern match with, not arguments.

The arguments are in the `<T1,T1>` part.  The compiler matches `<T1,T1>` against the passed arguments.

Any argument in a "deduced context" is matched independently.  So if you pass `<A,B>` it matches `T1=A` then `T1=B`.  This is inconsistent; the specialization does not match.  If you pass `<A,A>` it matches `T1=A` and `T1=A`.  This is consistent.

Things get fancier when you do `<T1*,T1*>`.  Then if you pass `<A,A>` it would try `T1*=A` and fail; but if passed `<A*,A*>` it would start with `T1*=A*`, then strip the `*` and get `T1=A`, then do that again for the 2nd argument.

Non-deduced contexts are different.  When you have a non-deduced context, like `std::enable_if_t<some_bool, T1>`, no pattern matching is done on that argument.  Instead the other arguments are pattern matched, then the specialization template variables are subsituted in.  If the resulting type matches the argument exactly, it passes; otherwise it fails.

The last bit is ordering.   If two secondary specializations pass, then whichever is strictly "more specialized" wins.  If neither is strictly more specialized, neither wins.  The rules for more specialized are complex; the intuitive idea is if one specialization could match the other's cases always, but not vice versa, the one that matches strictly less is more specialized.